# NextJS redux-saga sample code doesn't work with redux-saga ^1.0.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I'm working on connecting Next.js and redux-saga in a large existing React project.  I am following the Next.js sample code for this.  The sample code works fine, but when I tried to move the Next.js redux-saga sample code -- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux-saga --, my data wasn't getting stored in the store.  I'm not sure if my action to store it is being called, or if it's being called late, but I end up with an empty store.

I was tracing through the output and saw that the redux-saga task seems to have a `done` field with the sample code, but with my code it has a `toPromise` field.

The only obvious difference I could see between the two projects was that the sample code uses redux-saga 0.16.0 and my project uses ^1.0.0.

When I switched my project to use redux-saga 0.16.0 it works fine.

Perhaps next-redux-saga, on which both of these projects depends, is looking for the `done` field?  Could it be something else?  I attach the two package.json fields, in case you spot something I didn't.  Thanks for any help!

Sample code package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-redux-saga",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "4.1.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "2.0.0",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-redux-saga": "3.0.0",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2"
  }
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "PAW-React",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/InterficieIS/PAW-React.git",
  "author": "Javier1177 <javierlopezblasco@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-wrap-in-js": "^1.1.0",
    "bulma": "^0.6.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.27",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jss": "^9.8.7",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.1.1",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-fonts": "^0.16.0",
    "next-redux-saga": "^3.0.0",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.4.0",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "command-line-args": "^4.0.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.41.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "PORT=3001 node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "export": "next export",
    "eslint": "eslint . --ext=\"js,jsx\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The react-redux release 1.0.0 brings along API breaking changes which aren't yet implemented in those project. Please keep track of the following issues and pull-requests to know more:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/6109

https://github.com/bmealhouse/next-redux-saga/issues/27

https://github.com/bmealhouse/next-redux-saga/pull/29

Best Regards